# How to retain &quot; as it is in the original string while parsing with JSOUP/JAVA

Tags: java, xml, jsoup

Jsoup parser working fine for `&amp;`, `&gt;`, `&lt;` but its converting for `&quot;` to `""`. How can I avoid this?

```
String xml = "<P><SPAN><A>&quot;New&quot;</A></SPAN></P>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "UTF-8", Parser.xmlParser());
System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

Input: `<P><SPAN><A>&quot;New&quot;</A></SPAN></P>`

Current output: `<P><SPAN><A>"New"</A></SPAN></P>`

Expected output:`<P><SPAN><A>&quot;New&quot;</A></SPAN></P>`

Comment: May I ask why you need this? It's completely legal to have unescaped quotes there. What is the bigger picture? I believe you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @RoToRa, I am adding some node without changing any content in the given `xml` string, I need content as it is without any modification.

Comment: You are not changing the content. `"New"`,  `&quot;New&quot;` (and for example, `&#34;New&#34;`) are all the same content.

Comment: Yeah but in some places I have `""` as well along with `&quot;` in same given string, hence i need the same string which i have to perform some operations on it later.

Comment: Why do you have `"` and `&quot;` in the same string and want to distinguish them? From an HTML view they are the same thing, so you can't expect a HTML parser to distinguish them. It looks like you are misusing the HTML entities in some way. Maybe you should have `&quot;` escaped as `&amp;quot;`?

Comment: I have `""` inside tags which belongs to attributes but `&quot;` is resides under content between tags. So need the same string. Example `<P><SPAN style="color:red"><A>&quot;New&quot;</A></SPAN></P>`.

Comment: Then your problem isn't here, but the code that comes later and which can't distinguish between attribute quotes and quotes in the content. That's the code you need to fix.

Comment: My question is, its working fine with `&amp;`, `&gt;`, `&lt;` but why not for `&quot;`. if its treating others as well in the same way then we would have gone to some other options, but that is not the case here. I hope you got it.

Comment: In HTML `&`, `<` and `>` must always be escaped (or at least in most cases), but `"` only needs to be escaped inside an attribute value. Virtually all HTML parsers such as JSOUP, don't "remember" if a specific character was escaped or not when it reads it, so when it's written again Jsoup uses it own rules to decide what to escape and want not. And Jsoup doesn't have a API to control these rules. Jsoup simply creates valid HTML, and `"New"` and `&quot;New&quot;` are completely equal and completely equally valid. If your later code can't handle that, then that code needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

To get the output you want a solution would be to use regular expressions:

```
String xml= "<P><SPAN><A>&quot;New&quot;</A></SPAN></P>".replaceAll("&([^;]+?);", "**$1;");

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml);

doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false).escapeMode(EscapeMode.extended);

System.out.println(doc.outerHtml().replaceAll("\\*\\*([^;]+?);", "&$1;"));
```

Output: `<P><SPAN><A>&quot;New&quot;</A></SPAN></P>`

Comment: This will break if the original HTML contains `**`.

Comment: That's right, but considering that, you can enter ```**```  or XXX or another sequence of characters if necessary.

Comment: Yes it fails, if HTML has `**` in the content. Dont we have any inbuilt methods get the content as it is from `JSOUP`